# what would happen if you use belongs_to without having a corresponding has_one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a core model for an `Item`, and a script to populate it from a custom source (think, RSS feed). In the feed, each Item is identified with a `guid`; in my system, Item only has an autogenerated `id` primary key.

I want to have, let's say, `ItemFeedInfo` that maps `guid->id` (so that I can distinguish between new vs. modified Items)

I'm thinking of creating

```
class ItemFeedInfo
  belongs_to :Item
end
```

I would prefer not to modify `Item` since its definition is logically independent of `ItemFeedInfo` However, every example I can find of using `belongs_to`, mentions a `has_one` counterpart. Is it required?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

`belongs_to` simply adds some methods to the `ItemFeedInfo` class. You know when you do `item_feed_info.items.find_all`... The `items` is just a method which got dynamically added when you called `belongs_to`.

If you don't modify the `Item` class, then you simply won't be adding the methods on the other side. You won't be able to do `item.item_feed_infos.find_all`, because without adding `has_many :item_feed_infos`, that method won't have been added to the `Item` class, but if you never actually need to do this, it won't matter.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I couldnt find this info anywhere else (maybe I should look harder..).