# How do I create two relationships to the same model with different names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-models

I have two Rails 4 models: Journey and Place. I would like a Journey two have two fields, origin and destination, that are both Places. My Journey class looks like this:

```
class Journey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :origin, class_name: :place
  has_one :destination, class_name: :place
end
```

Firstly, do I also need something in my Place class? I thought I would need two "has_many" declarations, but I couldn't work out the syntax given the two references.

Secondly, would it be possible to reference the origin Place of a Journey using syntax like "j.Origin", where "j" is a Journey record? (And similarly for the destination.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, these relations should work for you:

```
class Journey < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :origin,      class_name: :place
  belongs_to :destination, class_name: :place
end

class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :origin_journeys,      foreign_key: origin_id,      class_name: :journey
  has_many :destination_journeys, foreign_key: destination_id, class_name: :journey

  def all_journeys
    Journey.where("origin_id = :place_id OR destination_id = :place_id", place_id: self.id)
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
# controller for exemple
def journeys_of_that_place
  @place = Place.find(params[:id])
  @journeys = @place.all_journeys
  @having_this_place_as_origin = @place.origin_journeys
end

# Question 2: Yes, it is possible
def update_origin
  @journey = Journey.find(params[:id])
  @journey.origin = Place.find(params[:place_id])
  @journey.save
end
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. You don't need anything in your `Place` class unless you want to be able to access `Journey` records from a `Place`.  However, you will need a foreign key `journey_id` on the `places` table.

   I'd consider setting up scopes on `Place` that would return `Journey` objects which started or ended in that place, if you think you might need them.  Check out the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one) on `has_one` and `belongs_to`.
2. Yep.  That's what the association is there for.  [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698986/what-would-happen-if-you-use-belongs-to-without-having-a-corresponding-has-one) may help shed some light on it as well.